# Weird problem: Pavucontrol vs. Alsamixer (Soundblaster Audigy RX Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, pavucontrol

I installed a Soundblaster Audigy RX card in my system:
I opened the case, put in the Soundblaster, closed it again and booted the machine, directly entering BIOS and disabling the onboard sound chipset.

In the dualboot Win10, installation and setup were without problem and it runs fine.
In Ubuntu 20.10 I had no sound. Alsamixer showed the card, but I had no output.

When I opened pavucontrol and selected the 'Analog Stereo out' option, nothing happened. When I selected 'Analog Stereo Out and Digital Mono In' I suddenly had sound. Heureka. No wait.
Upon closing pavucontrol, the sound persisted for about 5 seconds, then I was back to silence.

I found a fix for that:
in /etc/pulse/default.pa the following line needed to be disabled:

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
 load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Now I have sound, but I can only access the volume in the first section of pavucontrol.
When I use the system sound options, I can mute the sound. When I turn it up, I get about half volume around 1-2%, full volume at 3% and no change until I reach 100%. When I go beyond that, it gets a bit louder.

When I enter alsamixer, I can basically do what I want, to no effect.

cat /proc/asound/cards

```
enter code here0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                  HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
 1 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Meteorite Mic
                      Samson Technologies Samson Meteorite Mic at usb-0000:05:00.0-2.2, full speed
 2 [Audigy2        ]: Audigy2 - SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550]
                      SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550] (rev.0, serial:0x10241102) at 0xd000, irq 16
```

I'm at my wit's end. Any Ideas?